# Python Object to json for jquery

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, json, flask

I have code that gives me an object. I would like to send this object to jquery (ajax).

```
def create(country):
class Operator:
    def __init__(self, name, id, a,b,c):
        self.name = name
        self.operator_id = id
        self.product_type = self.Products(a,b,c)

    class Products:
        def __init__(self ,a,b,c):
            self.name = "Data"
            self.product_info = self.Items(a,b,c)


        class Items:
            def __init__(self, a,b,c):
                self.min_value = a
                self.max_value = b
                self.currency = c



data = []

for operator in country.product_details:
   provider_name = get_provider(operator)
   product_name = get_product(operator)

   data.append(Operator(provider_name.name, provider_name.provider_id, 
                        operator.a ,operator.b, operator.c))


return data
```

This returns an array of objects with data in it. After looking online, I found that

```
json.dumps(data, indent=4, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)
```

was the way to convert it to json for ajax. `Console.log` shows jquery is getting the below data as a one liner string.

```
[
{
    "name": "test",
    "operator_id": 1,
    "product_type": {
        "name": "Data",
        "product_info": {
            "min_value": 1,
            "max_value": 1,
            "currency": "test"
        }
    }
},
```

My Javascript code.

```
$(function()
{

$('.search-form').on('submit', function (event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/getprod',
                data: $('form').serialize(),
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    $(response.name).each(function(){
                        console.log ("works")
                    });

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            }
        );

    }
)
}
)
```

I try doing a for each of this but it isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since we can't see your Javascript code, it's really quite hard to say what you might be doing wrong. Also you should fix the indentation in your Python code.

Comment: why do you need a for-each loop? your code appears to work fine. `json.dumps(obj)` takes the entire object and will serialize to a JSON formatted string that you can pass to jquery. `json.dumps(data, indent=4, default=lambda x: x.__dict__)` should produce `[
    {
        "operator_id": 1, 
        "product_type": {
            "product_info": {
                "max_value": 1, 
                "min_value": 1, 
                "currency": "test"
            }, 
            "name": "Data"
        }, 
        "name": "test"
    }, 
    {...etc.`

Comment: I added the jquery. Concerning the indentation, should'nt I do it that way to have a class of classes to  make an object of objects? Without the default=lambda x: x.__dict__ , I get an error saying, "TypeError: Object of type Operator is not JSON serializable"

Comment: As I suspected, seeing the Javascript reveals the problem. `$(response.name)`, with the response shown, is `$("test")`, which is not going to find any elements. As for the Python indentation, you have a function definition on the first line, and an unindented line immediately below. I'm sure this is a copy-paste error, but it makes it hard to be sure that the rest of your indentation is really as shown here.